# Value returned by a getter from smart contract instead of uint : org.web3j.protocol.core.RemoteCall@5104cf00 - spring boot - web3j

Tags: go-ethereum, web3j

```
pragma solidity ^0.4.18;

contract MyDeal {

  /// The seller's address
  address public owner;
  /// The buyer's address part on this contract
  address public buyerAddr;

  /// The Buyer struct  
  struct Buyer {
    address addr;
    string name;

    bool init;
  }
  /// The Order struct
  struct Order {
    string goods;
    uint quantity;
    uint number;
    uint price;
    uint safepay;
    uint deliveryDate;

    bool init;
  }
  /// The Invoice struct (facture)
  struct Invoice {
    uint orderno;
    uint number;

    bool init;
  }

  /// The mapping to store orders
  mapping (uint => Order) orders;
  /// The mapping to store invoices
  mapping (uint => Invoice) invoices;


  /// The sequence number of orders
  uint public orderseq;
  /// The sequence number of invoices
  uint public invoiceseq;

  /// Event triggered for every registered buyer
  event BuyerRegistered(address buyer, string name);
  /// Event triggered for every new order
  event OrderSent(address buyer, string goods, uint quantity, uint orderno);
  /// Event triggerd when the order gets valued and wants to know the value of the payment
  event PriceSent(address buyer, uint orderno, uint price);
  /// Event trigger when the buyer performs the safepay
  event SafepaySent(address buyer, uint orderno, uint value, uint now);
  /// Event triggered when the seller sends the invoice
  event InvoiceSent(address buyer, uint invoiceno, uint orderno, uint delivery_date);
  /// Event triggered when the seller delives the order
   event OrderDelivered(address buyer, uint invoiceno, uint orderno, uint real_delivey_date,
   address owner);

  /// The smart contract's constructor
  constructor(address _buyerAddr) public {
    /// The seller is the contract's owner
    owner = msg.sender;
    buyerAddr = _buyerAddr;
  }

///getters  
    function getOwner() view public returns (address) {
        return owner;
    }
    function getBuyer() view public returns (address) {
        return buyerAddr;
    }
    function getInvoiceseq() view public returns (uint) {
        return invoiceseq;
    }
    function getOrderseq() view public returns (uint) {
        return orderseq;
    }
    function getMsgSender() view public returns (address) {
        return msg.sender;
    }

  ///To get field values listen to OrderSent event.
  function sendOrder(string goods, uint quantity) payable public {
    /// Accept orders just from buyer
    require(msg.sender == buyerAddr);
    /// Increment the order sequence
    orderseq++;
    /// Create the order register
    orders[orderseq] = Order(goods, quantity, orderseq, 0, 0, 0, true);
    /// Trigger the event
    emit OrderSent(msg.sender, goods, quantity, orderseq);
  }

  /// The function to query orders by number
  /// Constant functions returns custom fields
  function queryOrder(uint number) constant public returns (address buyer, string goods, uint quantity, uint price, uint safepay) {
    /// Validate the order number
    require(orders[number].init);
    /// Return the order data
    return(buyerAddr, orders[number].goods, orders[number].quantity, orders[number].price, orders[number].safepay);
  }

  /// The function to send the price to pay for order
  function sendPrice(uint orderno, uint price) payable public {
    /// Only the owner can use this function
    require(msg.sender == owner);
    /// Validate the order number
    require(orders[orderno].init);
    /// Update the order price
    orders[orderno].price = price;
    /// Trigger the event
    emit PriceSent(buyerAddr, orderno, price);
  }

  /// The function to send the value of order's price
  ///  This value will be blocked until the delivery of order
  ///  requires fee
  function sendSafepay(uint orderno) payable public {
    /// Validate the order number
    require(orders[orderno].init);
    /// Just the buyer can make safepay
    require(buyerAddr == msg.sender);
    /// The order's value must equal to msg.value
    require((orders[orderno].price) == msg.value);
    orders[orderno].safepay = msg.value;
    emit SafepaySent(msg.sender, orderno, msg.value, now);
  }

  /// The function to send the invoice data
  ///  requires fee
  function sendInvoice(uint orderno, uint delivery_date) payable public {
    /// Validate the order number
    require(orders[orderno].init);
    /// Just the seller can send the invoice
    require(owner == msg.sender);
    invoiceseq++;
    /// Create then Invoice instance and store it
    invoices[invoiceseq] = Invoice(orderno, invoiceseq, true);
    /// Update the shipment data
    orders[orderno].deliveryDate = delivery_date;
    /// Trigger the event
    emit InvoiceSent(buyerAddr, invoiceseq, orderno, delivery_date);
  }

  /// The function to get the sent invoice
  ///  requires no fee
  function getInvoice(uint invoiceno) constant public returns (address buyer, uint orderno, uint delivery_date){
    /// Validate the invoice number
    require(invoices[invoiceno].init);
    Invoice storage _invoice = invoices[invoiceno];
    Order storage _order     = orders[_invoice.orderno];
    return (buyerAddr, _order.number, _order.deliveryDate);
  }

  /// The function to mark an order as delivered
  function delivery(uint invoiceno, uint timestamp) payable public {
    /// Validate the invoice number
    require(invoices[invoiceno].init);
    Invoice storage _invoice = invoices[invoiceno];
    Order storage _order     = orders[_invoice.orderno];
    /// Just the seller (owner) can call this function
    require(msg.sender == owner);
    emit OrderDelivered(buyerAddr, invoiceno, _order.number, timestamp, owner);
    /// Payout the Order to the seller
    owner.transfer(_order.safepay);
  }

  function health() pure public returns (string) {
    return "running";
  }
}
```

Code to deploy and load contract

public MyContract createContract(MyContract newContract) throws Exception {
        buyerAddr = template.getForObject(url, String.class);
        LOGGER.info("Buyer adress is here : {} ", buyerAddr);

```
    contract = MyDeal.deploy(web3j, credentialsSeller, GAS_PRICE, GAS_LIMIT, buyerAddr).send();

    newContract.setBuyer(buyerAddr);
    newContract.setAddress(contract.getContractAddress());
    newContract.setSeller(credentialsSeller.getAddress());

    contracts.add(contract.getContractAddress());
    LOGGER.info("Address={} added to contracts list",contract.getContractAddress());
    LOGGER.info("New contract deployed: address={}", contract.getContractAddress());

    Optional<TransactionReceipt> tr = contract.getTransactionReceipt();
    if (tr.isPresent()) {
        LOGGER.info("Transaction receipt: hash={}, from={}, to={}, gas={}", tr.get().getTransactionHash(), tr.get().getFrom(), tr.get().getTo(), tr.get().getGasUsed().intValue());
    }
    /*Subscription s = contract.buyerRegisteredEventObservable(DefaultBlockParameterName.LATEST, DefaultBlockParameterName.LATEST)
            .subscribe(evento ->{
                        LOGGER.info("Event Received");
                    }, Throwable::printStackTrace);

    s.unsubscribe();*/
    Thread.sleep(500);

    return newContract;
}
public Boolean loadContract() throws Exception {

    MyDeal loadedContract = MyDeal.load(contract.getContractAddress(), web3j, credentialsSeller, GAS_PRICE, GAS_LIMIT );
    //LOGGER.info("orderseq is : {}",loadedContract.getOrderseq().send());

    return loadedContract.isValid();
}`
```

Comment: ` <dependency>
   <groupId>org.web3j</groupId>
   <artifactId>web3j-spring-boot-starter</artifactId>
   <version>1.6.0</version>
  </dependency>`

Comment: What is your code to call the getter?

Comment: i found that my problem is in loading contract, when using isValid() after deploying the contract, a "false" is returning
and i can't find the reason

Comment: result : 
New contract deployed: address=0x1e83957755df71a57f27d2efeb07696c2dec8691
2018-08-27 04:25:51.983  INFO 89984 --- [nio-8090-exec-1] c.s.s.c.s.stage.service.MyService        : Transaction receipt: hash=0x391756cc2544509a203e56c56fe5c01b7e76d81a1be814993a976093cf2abe41, from=0xdbca4f5a1c56b925a69575e128a8b01df100da71, to=null, gas=500000
2018-08-27 04:25:56.168  INFO 89984 --- [nio-8090-exec-2] c.s.s.c.s.stage.service.MyService        : Loading Contract..
2018-08-27 04:25:56.669  INFO 89984 --- [nio-8090-exec-2] c.s.s.c.s.stage.service.MyService        : Contract isValid : false

Answer (score 1):

it was a GAS problem
i used
       BigInteger GAS = Contract.GAS_LIMIT;
       BigInteger GAS_PRICE = Contract.GAS_PRICE; to solve it.